# Stream Video from a self-written Server to Android App

Tags: java, android, video, tcp, streaming

I want to write a "simple" Java Server-type application to stream videos to different clients. My first step would be an again "simple" Android App containing a VideoView and a MediaPlayer set to Video Streaming ([More Information on Android SDK - MediaPlayer](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html)) though later i might add desktop java application too.

What i'm not sure is how i would actually do the streaming on the server. I already wrote a little Http Server processing HTTP GET requests from a client over TCP.
There i write/"stream" the files back using this coding:

```
FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream(f);
final byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int count = 0;

//add the header information to the respone

while ((count = fs.read(buffer)) >= 0) {
  os.write(buffer, 0, count);
}

os.flush();
fs.close();
os.close();
```

os being the OutputStream of the Response i get through the tcp socket and f being the requested file.
This seems to send the file almost completly at once though and not like i want to, stream it "in chunks".

So my questions are:

- What do i, or do i have to change my coding to actually stream the video, or is it already correct this way?
- When i want to make it using UDP instead of TCP would i then only put the buffer byte arrays read from the fileinputstream directly into the DatagramPacket and the MediaPlayer would know what to do with it?

PS: I know there are several questions on here about streaming in Java but none of them actually cover the server side but mainly the (in this case Android-) client side.

Comment: After a bit of looking around i can see the xuggler library popping up quite often and people saying that udp and tcp are probably not natively supported by Android. Is that correct? Do i / Should i use Xuggler to do my streaming? If so do i need another library or is java standard + Xuggler enough to stream videos?

Comment: Another thing i'm wondering is wether the Android media player can manage state?